# Eclipse F3 Shortcut Backtrack

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I couldn't discover the answer on google, stack overflow, or figure it out within 5 minutes in the IDE.

**My question is for the F3 shortcut which lets you follow references to functions, classes, etc., is there another hotkey or option to backtrack where you went?**

I love this F3 hotkey but while I'm reading through code but sometimes, I have to go through multiple functions so I wanna backtrack it.

Comment: woops, was a stupid question. i fail. thanks all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use shortcut:

```
Alt + Left Arrow
```

Comment: To add to your answer, Alt + Right to go forward in editor history too :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Alt + <-` (left key) to return to where you were.

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut is *Alt + Left Arrow Key*

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> returns to the called place.